# Function overload for pointer to abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading, c++98

I'm having some trouble with function overloading in C++.

I have a class hierarchy where many classes inherit from an abstract base class, like this:

```
struct Animal {
  virtual void make_noise() = 0;
};

struct Dog : Animal {
  void make_noise() { std::cout << "bark\n"; }
};

struct Cat : Animal {
  void make_noise() { std::cout << "meow\n"; }
};

struct Lion : Cat {
  void make_noise() { std::cout << "roar\n"; }
};
```

I want to have a function which has three different implementations depending on the type of the argument:

- One for pointers to subclasses of `Animal`: `Dog *`, `Lion *`, etc.
- One for vectors of pointers to subclasses of `Animal`: `std::vector<Animal *>`, `std::vector<Lion *>`, etc.
- One for every other type, even those which aren't pointers: `char *`, `std::string`, `int`, etc.

Here is my attempt:

```
void f(Animal *x) {
  x->make_noise();
}

void f(std::vector<Animal *> x) {
  std::cout << "vector\n";
}

template<class T>
void f(T a) {
  std::cout << a << "\n";
}

int main() {
  f(new Lion);
  std::vector<Animal *> x;
  f(x);
  f(2);
  return 0;
}
```

This is what the above program prints:

```
0x7febb8d00000
vector
2
```

This is what I want it to print:

```
roar
vector
2
```

Additionally, if I try to pass a `std::vector<Lion *>` instead of a `std::vector<Animal *>`, it chooses the last implementation instead of the second implementation and generates a compiler error.

How can I fix this in C++98?

Comment: For staters, a function that takes a `std::vector<Animal *>` parameter is not going to accept a `std::vector<Lion *>` instead, no matter what. The two vector template instances are different classes that have no relationship to each other, whatsoever. Just because one template's parameter is a pointer to the base class of the other template's parameter does not make the first template a derived class of the second template. C++ does not work this way. I think you need to spend a little bit more time studying how templates and classes work, in C++, and boning up on some fundamentals, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use template specialization and specifying the template param type in the call to f as follows:

```
template<class T>
void f(T a) {
  std::cout << a << "\n";
}

template<>
void f(Animal *x) {
  x->make_noise();
}

template<>
void f(std::vector<Animal *> x) {
  std::cout << "vector\n";
}


int main() {
  f<Animal *>(new Lion); // specify template param
  std::vector<Animal *> x;
  f(x);
  f(2);
  return 0;
}
```